# Proxy wss nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, websocket, proxy

I'm trying to configure nginx config for wss proxy, but in the browser console, I have seen an error about wss connection failed.

For http it's working perfectly, idk how to make a proxy correctly. Try a lot of variants but don't understand where is issue.

```
upstream websocket {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default Upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl        on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;
        root /var/www/xxx/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location /wss/ { // that's is copy from another thread (path 'wss' is correct)
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            keepalive_timeout 86400s;
            # prevents 502 bad gateway error
            proxy_buffers 8 32k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            reset_timedout_connection on;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Enveriment

this config works well on nginx 1.21.6

### nginx config content

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    # Sending fille Optimization
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    # Keepalive Connection
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
    upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:8010;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
        location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.websocket.app;

        # Security and SSL
        ssl_certificate  "./cert/server.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key  "./cert/server.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 SSLv2 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.20.225:29999;
        }
     }
}
```

## test method

```
curl -i --header "Upgrade: websocket" --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: MlRAR6bQZi07587UD4H8oA==" --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" https://172.16.20.51:443 -k
```